# Order of Code Execution

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

**HTML**:

```
<head>

<script>
var sharedValue = {a:"b"}
</script>

<script src="otherScript.js"></script>

<script>
console.log(sharedValue);
</script>

</head>
```

**otherScript.js**

```
sharedValue.b = "a";
```

Is it possible that the console.log in the head will output `{a:"b"}` if `otherScript.js` takes too long to load? or will it always be `{a:"b",b:"a"}`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will always be `{a:"b", b:"a"}`.  Execution in the browser is serial and blocking.